# Generalizing the expected value of an urn problem with number fixed draws

Tags: probability, combinatorics

So we have an urn problem with two colors of balls, red and black. Say each ball has a value on it, x and y, for red and black, respectively. You have n number of draws, game ends when you run out of draws.

With two draws the probability of getting one black and one red is $\frac{r}{r+b}\frac{b}{r+b-1} + \frac{b}{r+b}\frac{r}{a+b-1}=2\frac{b}{r+b}\frac{r}{r+b-1}$. The probability of two red is $\frac{r(r-1)}{(a+b)(a+b-1)}$. So the expected value of this problem with two draws is:

E(2 draws)= $\frac{r(r-1)}{(a+b)(a+b-1)}(2x)+2\frac{b}{r+b}\frac{r}{r+b-1}(x+y)+\frac{b(b-1)}{(a+b)(a+b-1)}(2y) $

So the question is, how do we generalize this problem with n draws? Assuming that n is smaller than the total number of balls of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the linearity of expectation, your expected winnings after $n$
draws is $n$ times your expected winnings after one draw.

Comment: Does that not assume that there is replacement?

Comment: It really doesn't matter. The total winnings is $W_1+\cdots+W_n$ where $W_j$ is the winning on the $j$-th draw. The $W_j$ are identically distributed (maybe not independent by that doesn't matter).